Isekai where the female lead is reincarnated and her family is from the medicine field
I'm looking for an isekai where the female lead is reincarnated and her family is from the medicine field. She prevents the male lead's trauma by saving his mother from the attack of her stalker, who turns out to be her mother's nephew.
It wasn't completed or something. But it was definitely from  a book or manga.

This is I Was Reincarnated as the Villainess in an Otome Game but the Boys Love Me Anyway! It is licensed by Tokyopop.

Mystia Aren is the daughter of a noble family who just started at high school. She’s surrounded by a group of adoring classmates and her charming fiancé. Everything seems perfect. Except that this world is actually a dating sim called “Kyun Love”, and she’s destined to become the main character’s evil rival!

There are some additional details in this old answer of mine.
The protagonist realizes one day that she reincarnated in the world of a game, and therefore is aware of some future events. One of these is that her fiance's mother will be killed by a stalker,

It is explicitly mentioned that the stalker is her nephew. There's also a comment in the first chapter that her family is medically-focused. I can't recall if anything comes of that or if it's just flavor text.
She protects the mother by securing the carriage door with a rope and waiting for the authorities to apprehend the nephew.

